# Erro na inserção de dados : String data, right truncated: 1406 laravel

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando salvar os dados do checklist do protocolo, mas está ocorrendo o seguinte erro no momento de salvar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A espectativa é que aconteça isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na descrição do erro informa que o tipo inserido não comporta o armazenamento no banco de dados, ou seja, a inserção está uma linha com todos os dados.

Segue a estrutura do banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o detalhes dos campos do banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a impressão das variáveis:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código Model ProjetoController.php como o método cadastroChecklistProtocolo

```
public function cadastroChecklistProtocolo(Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request->request);
        $dados = $request->only(['item', 'item_descricao_id', 'sim_nao', 'nao_atende', 'dt_validade', 'pagina_documento', 'observacao']);

        //$checklistsProtocolos = new ChecklistProtocolo;
        $checklistsProtocolos  = ChecklistProtocolo::create($dados);
        $checklistsProtocolos->save($dados);



   //echo '<pre>';
     //dd($dados);  //imprimir as variaveis na tela.          

     $response = true;

        if($response)
        {
            return redirect()
                      ->route('projeto.edita', $request->projeto_id) 
                      ->with('success',"Sucesso ao atualizar os Checklists do Protocolo");
        }else
        {
            return redirect()
                      ->back()
                      ->with('error',"Erro ao atualizar o Checklists do Protocolo"); 
        } 
    }
```

Código Model ChecklistProtocolo.php:

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;
use SoftDeletes;

class ChecklistProtocolo extends Model
{
    protected $table = "checklist_protocolo";

```
protected $primaryKey =  ['projeto_id', 'modelo_id','itens_descricao_id'];

public $incrementing = false;

public $timestamps = false;

protected  $fillable  = ['projeto_id', 'modelo_id','item','item_descricao_id','sim_nao', 'nao_atende','dt_validade','pagina_documento','observacao'];

protected $casts = [ 'item' => 'array', 'item_descricao_id'=> 'array','sim_nao' => 'array', 'dt_validade'=> 'array', 
'pagina_documento'=> 'array', 'observacao'=> 'array', 'nao_atende'=> 'array']; 

/* 
public function checklistProtocolo()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(ChecklistProtocolo::class, 'projeto_id','modelo_id', 'itens_descricao_id');
} */

//Este método salva os dados do Checklist do Protocolo
public function salvar(ChecklistProtocolo $checklistProtocolo) : Array
{
   $checklistProtocolo = $this->save();

     if($checklistProtocolo){

        return[
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Sucesso ao cadastrar'
        ];   
    }
    else{

        return[
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Falha ao cadastrar'
        ]; 
    }
}
```

O código de exibição edita.blade.php do checklist:

```
 @foreach($checklistsProtocolos as $checklistProtocolo)

                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"  id="item" name="item[]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->item}}"  size ="2"></td>
                                    <td>{{$checklistProtocolo->descricao_item}}</td>   
                                    <input type="hidden"          id="item_descricao_id"  name="item_descricao_id[]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->item_descricao_id}}">
                                    <td><input type="checkbox"    id="sim_nao"            name="sim_nao[]"    {{$checklistProtocolo->sim_nao == null ? '' : 'checked'}}></td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox"    id="nao_atende"         name="nao_atende[]" {{$checklistProtocolo->nao_atende == null ? '' : 'checked'}}></td>
                                    <td><input type="date"        id="dt_validade"        name="dt_validade[]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->dt_validade}}"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text"        id="pagina_documento"   name="pagina_documento[]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->pagina_documento}}" size ="1"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text"        id="observacao"         name="observacao[]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->observacao}}" size ="1" style="width: 300px; height: 60px"></td>
                                </tr>

                                @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução aplicada foi criar uma variável ($cont) para contar linha de cada array dentro do loop de repetição no método cadastroChecklistProtocolo.

Referência: 
[Salvar itens de um formulário checklist no banco - Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/382561/salvar-itens-de-um-formul%C3%A1rio-checklist-no-banco-laravel)

Segue código:

```
$cont = 0; //contador de linhas para os arrays

              for($i = 0; $i < count($dt_validade); $i++){

                   $dataInsert = array(
                         'sim_nao' => $sim_nao[$cont],                   
                         'dt_validade'=> $dt_validade[$cont], 
                         'pagina_documento' =>$pagina_documento[$cont], 
                         'observacao' =>$observacao[$cont]);           

                         $checklistsProtocolos = checklistProtocolo::where('projeto_id', $projeto_id)
                         ->whereIn('item_descricao_id', (array)$item_descricao_id[$cont])  //atualiza linha por linha do array
                         ->update($dataInsert);
                         $cont++; //atualiza linha por linha do array
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro é porque você está tentando registrar um array de datas numa coluna que seu tipo é data.

Não sei se tudo ficou bem claro pra mim no seu código, mas pelo que entendi vc quer salvar separadamente esses vários registros em linhas diferentes da tabela, caso seja isso você precia fazer um loop em cada opção vinda do request, assim criando os seus ChecklistProtocolo em sequencia e depois salvando. Se de fato deseja salvar o array de datas então é necessário substitui o tipo de coluna no sql.

Comment: Nesse caso estou precisando salvar os registros separadamente e nas suas respectivas linhas. Vou testar sua sugestão do loop em cada opção vinda do request.

Comment: Se não conseguir manda como ficou que te ajudo.

Comment: Atualizei a descrição da pergunta coloquei uma imagem do resultado esperado.

Comment: Fiz dessa forma:                                                                                                        
       foreach ($dados as $key => $value) {
       ChecklistProtocolo :: whereIn('item', $value)->create($dados);
     }                                                                                                                                                            O erro de inserção persiste.